# Adding text next to slideshow images

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

this is a code I modified it a little bit to make a simple slideshow with images using only HTML and CSS:

(This is a part of the code to see it all please click on demo)

Code:

```css
.slideshow {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

.slideshow-container {
  width: 2500px;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 1s ease;
  height: 225px;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  12.5% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  37.5% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  62.5% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  87.5% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  99% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-container slide">
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/625/225/any" />
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/625/225/animals" />
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/625/225/arch" />
  </div>
</section>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/GhaidaMK/pen/JprVNg)

I want to add a text next to each image, so in the frame I will have half of it image and the other half text.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: have a look at this bro --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204183/write-text-on-top-of-multiple-images/48204433#48204433

Comment: hm, try to make container div, include there image and text, style it. 20% width for text, another 80% for image for example.

Comment: If I put each img in a div only the first picture displays others not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will wrap your `image` and `text` part into a `.item` div.

Apply  `display:flex` to parent `.slideshow-container` to set `.item` in a row.

Then just apply `width:50%` to your `img` and `.caption` div to align them half of the screen

Also changed your animation animation partition values according to 3 items in a row

**[Fiddle Link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/buv33v4f/1/)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
/*general styles*/

body {
  padding: 3em;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/*slideshow styles*/

.slideshow {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px white;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  align-items: center;
}

.slideshow-container {
  width: 2400px;
  transition: 1s ease;
  display: flex;
}

.slideshow-container:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.slide {
  animation: slide 24s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  37.5% {
    transform: translateX(-33.333%);
  }
  62.5% {
    transform: translateX(-33.333%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-66.667%);
  }
  99% {
    transform: translateX(-66.667%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.item img {
  width: 50%
}

.item .caption {
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<!--hovering over the images will pause the slideshow -->

<section class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-container slide">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/625/225/any" />
      <div class="caption">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/625/225/animals" />
      <div class="caption">Text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placeimg.com/625/225/arch" />
      <div class="caption">Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```